# masked input plugin with variable argument

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I'm using the masked input plugin to mask some zip code input fields. This works great for most circumstances, however I can't figure out how to mask a UK postcode.

the problem arises because the UK pestcode has a spot that can have 1 or 2 digits. for example:

```
1x  1xx
1xx 1xx
```

the first example has one letter x in the first 3 digits, but the second has two letter x. I know how to use masked input to specify that I need at least 3 digits, but the rest are optional:

```
$('element').mask('***?***'); 

//* is for accepting alpha-numeric
//the above says 'I need at least 3 digits, the rest are optional'
```

however, how do I make an optional in the middle of the mask? and the rest are required?

also, does masked input accept regex?

Comment: You are using a non-native method of jQuery. Please include a link to the website (or doc) of the plugin you are using.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon this is what I'm using: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I've looked around the code and I don't think you can do what you want with that plugin.